# Update of a Folium map using TimestampedGeoJson

Tags: python-3.x, macos, jupyter-notebook, geojson, folium

First of all, I'm trying to modify the coordinates of my points in order to make them rotate on my map around a central point and I would like to be able to update them in real time from a GPS beacon.

But when I run my code, nothing appears but I don't have any error either. My "features" dictionary works as it should, just like "Pylones".

Does anyone have an idea how to unblock me?

```
import folium
from folium import plugins

Pylones = [
    {
        "coordinates":[-1.11246912+0.025,44.54890465+0.025],
        "dates":["2017-06-02T00:00:00"],
        "numéro": "Bigare"
    },{
        "coordinates":[-1.11246912+0.025,44.54890465+0.025],
        "dates":["2017-06-02T00:10:00"],
        "numéro": "Bigare"
    },{
        "coordinates":[-1.11246912+0.025,44.54890465+0.025],
        "dates":["2017-06-02T00:20:00"],
        "numéro": "Bigare"
    },{
        "coordinates":[-1.11246912+0.025,44.54890465+0.025],
        "dates":["2017-06-02T00:30:00"],
        "numéro": "Bigare"
    },{
        "coordinates":[-1.11246912+0.025,44.54890465+0.025],
        "dates":["2017-06-02T00:40:00"],
        "numéro": "Bigare"
    }
]

for aa in range(5):
    for bb in range(5):
        Pylones.append(
            {
                "coordinates":[-1.11246912+0.025*math.sin(aa*2*math.pi/5+bb*2*math.pi/5),
                               44.54890465+0.025*math.cos(kk*2*math.pi/5+ll*2*math.pi/5)],
                "dates":["2017-06-02T00:"+str(bb)+"0:00"],
                "numéro": str(aa+1)
            }
         )
        
features = [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": Pylone["coordinates"],
        },
        "properties": {
            "times": Pylone["dates"],
            "tooltip": "info",
            "popup" : ("<b>"+Pylone["numéro"]+"</b>"),
            "numéro" : Pylone["numéro"],
            "icon" : "info-sign",
            "color" : "green"
        },
    }
    for Pylone in Pylones
]

center_pt = [44.53107, -1.11288]

maps = folium.Map(location=center_pt, zoom_start=13)

plugins.TimestampedGeoJson(
    {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": features,
    },
    period="PT1M",
    duration="PT5M",
    add_last_point=True,
).add_to(maps)

maps
```

Comment: I am not clear what you are trying to achieve. You say the coordinates of the point, but the data specifies a LineString. If you change this to Point, the animation will move. Also, what do you mean by unblocking in your comment?

Comment: @r-beginners, thanks for your help, i forgot to change this from the code i used. i meant "help" with "unblocked", sorry a french expression literally translated.